# Android.ImageButton: Background Image cycling replacement

Tags: android, thread-safety, imagebutton

There is a set of PNG files which emulate drawing the Ok tick. Pls, see the image.
I attached just 3 of them to give you good understanding.

[image]
[image]
[image]

In C# I use several techniques:
 - Thread + delegate.. where I run Thread with Sleep and Invoke the delegate to update button back image.
 - Background worker - very similar to 1
 - Timer.. Run Timer and onTick do the replacement.

I tried Timer in Android. Didn't work.. I think because in fact Timer in Android is also another Thread and changing a View properties onTick comes to App crush.
There is no Thread safe delegates also..
I know the Animation issue, and I use it to move the same button image left-right (shaking effect)..

So, please, tell me:

1) How to Animate an Image Button my way (replacing background images) using Animation package?
2) I've heard something about delayed post of timer event.. but I can't find its good sample. Pls, explain briefly that technique.

Thanks

Theresult code (answer)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_test); 

final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { 
public void run() { 
SetNextImage(); 
handler.postDelayed(this, 50); 
} 
}; 
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 50); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imageView.postDelayed(Runnable r, long timeMilliSec)
```

Try this it will get called after the time you set and then in the run method you can change the image and post another delay for 3rd image.

Comment: Hi Umar, it works! Thanks.. Pls, publish the next code to close the case:     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_test);
        //t.schedule(new OnTick(), 100);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                SetNextImage();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 50);
    }